# How to change order of elements when device is mobile

Tags: javascript, css

I have sth like this

```
<div className="Image"><div><div className="Text"><div>
<div className="Text"><div><div className="Image"><div>
<div className="Image"><div><div className="Text"><div>
```

How to swap content between my divs when device is mobile??

Is any trick for it? Or should i write a code again for mobile?
I use bootstrap and flex box.

Comment: Swap how? If it's a simple reversal of the order then flexbox will do nicely. Otherwise, you might find grid-template-areas to do the job well.

Comment: Are you trying to re-order them in the DOM, or is what you really want just to reorder them visually? JS is required for the first option, but CSS can (and should) be used if the goal is to create a mobile friendly layout.

Comment: the order which is  in my comment is ok big for screens but when i go to mobile i have mess like image text image image text. This is becouse i have all elements vertically

Comment: that's called building a responsive design. there's many ways to do that

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: my i idea is to find size of the window and then swap content according to className using js

Comment: Do you want it on mobile to be: Image Text Image Text Image Text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), you can use [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.order-1{
  order:1;
}
.order-2{
  order:2;
}
.order-3{
  order:3;
}
@media(min-width:992px){
  .order-lg-1{
    order:1;
  }
  .order-lg-2{
    order:2;
  }
  .order-lg-3{
    order:3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="order-3 order-lg-2">A</div>
  <div class="order-2 order-lg-1">B</div>
  <div class="order-1 order-lg-3">C</div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

div is originally display: block. You may have to put an outside div to envelop the three divs you have and apply display: flex.

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div className="Image">image<div>           
  <div className="Text">text<div>            
  <div className="Image">image<div>            
</div>
```

When you reduce the screen size, the elements will be displayed in columns.